# Android ndk r7, ffmpeg on Windows

Tags: android, windows, ffmpeg

We are developing an android App which should convert the .3GP file to .FLV and upload to the web server.

We completed the overall framework to upload a file to web server.  But we are facing problem on converting the .3GP to .FLV.

We searched google and couldn't able to find a working solution.

1. We are using Windows OS
2. We managed to install the NDK r7
3. We managed to install cygwin.
4. We downloaded the latest ffmpeg

Now we need to compile the FFMPEG using the android NDK and use FFMPEG to convert the video file.

Could someone help me to compile ffmpeg on android (windows)?
Or is there any other way simplest way to convert a video?

Comment: Were you able to finally build FFmpeg libs for Android on Windows then ?

Answer (score -1):

you can see https://github.com/havlenapetr/FFMpeg/commits/debug
it works well.
and just google as "android ffpeg",it will be a bazinga